# Wrong id of tables in my database symfony

Tags: php, sql, symfony

I just create my first app in symfony and i have a problem with routing.

```
/**
 * @Route("/todo/details/{id}", name="todo_details")
 */
public function detailsAction($id){
   $todo = $this->getDoctrine()
   ->getRepository('AppBundle:Todo')
   ->find($id);

    return $this->render('todo/details.html.twig', array(
        'todo' => $todo
    ));       
}
```

I have code as this above. The problem is in {id}, because in my database i have three task and it's not matter that i click I always get the first. To show another i must change it manually.

Now i observed another problem. When i delete all task and create two new i have new id's for them. Is that situation is correct?

Comment: where and how do you generate the links in question?

Comment: i click on the button 'details' at my app.

Comment: I'm sure you do, but how do you generate the urls on those buttons? your question suggests that the problem is that you generate the same url over and over.

Comment: so in routing.yml file i have that 
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

Comment: I know you have. I pull myself out, if you choose to answer my question you can ping me.

Comment: Ok i solved that. I have wrong directory in file where I generated url. Thanks for the tips